# Windows 10 PsExec localhost

Tags: windows-10, psexec

The following command generally works fine on Windows 7 and Windows 10:

```
psexec \\machine -u username -p password -h -c -f script.bat
```

However, on Windows 10 when 'machine' is the localhost, I receive the error below:

```
Could not start PSEXESVC on localhost:
Access is denied.
```

The error message goes away if I run the command at an elevated prompt. Is there anyway to avoid this? What specifically is causing the issue on the local machine on Windows 10?

Comment: This is due to the differences between Windows 10 and Windows 7, Windows 10 elevates a process by implicit request from a user, Windows 7 didn't require that

Answer (score 0):

```
psexec \\machine -u USERNAMR -p PASSWORD -h -c -f script.bat
```

or just omit *-p PASSWORD* to securely prompt for password:

```
psexec \\machine -u USERNAMR -h -c -f script.bat
```

`-h` is to "run with the account's elevated token, **if available**". So, if you don't run your CMD with elevated privileges, no elevated token is available! There's nothing wrong with Windows. It needs either an elevated token, or elevated credentials to gain that token.

Comment: On the first point, I was already entering the password, so I've amended my question to reflect that.

On your second point, why does Windows not require an elevated token when running the script on a remote machine?

Comment: What version of Windows, the command should require a UAC prompt on any version of Windows greater than 8.

Comment: The local and target machines are both running Windows 10. When running psexec on the local machine, from a non-elevated prompt, script.bat runs on the target machine elevated. However, this doesn't happen if the local and target machine are the same. The user is a domain account in the Administrators group on both machines.

Comment: You are right. My guess is it needs to access \\localhost\admin$ and that's an administrative share. so, because it's a local address, it tries to use the current token, instead the credentials you provided.

Comment: @Ramhound
I just tried on a system with disabled UAC and `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` set to disabled (accesible administrative share from network) and still no luck! It's something sysinternals should fix.